# will rpi4 be powerful enough to handle my db queries

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

Hello I’m thinking of buying the rpi4 with 8gb ram.
I’m primarily going to be using it as a database for personal queries. I’m new to databases and I’m currently researching many options.

I would have 100s of millions of objects stored in the following format: {a:12345678, b:123456789000, c:123, d: 23, e: true} . I will be querying from the entire db something like this : query all the c values where b is between 123456789000 to 123456899000. Or query everything in the object where b is between 123456789000 to 123456899000.

I won’t be doing any database manipulation. Only db reads.

I would be querying 100,000 to a million objects at a time. Query frequency would probably max out at 2-5 queries per second. But on average, probably 1 query per second. I read that sqlite / sqlite3 are quite lightweight so I would like to test it out. If you have any other suggestions, please add here. And finally will the rpi4 be powerful enough to handle these requests ?

Comment: napkin maths suggests your database may be 10's of gigabytes in size, so I gather you won't be using an SD card for the storage - which is good. A decent USB3 to SATA with an SSD will improve the likelihood of this working for you

Comment: Yeah the plan is to get an ssd. Query size I think will range between 50-100mb. Do you think rpi4 will be able to query the data in sub milliseconds?

Comment: so less than 1 millisecond?

Comment: Like 50-100ms would be okay with me.